# How to filter by one column when that column belongs to a composite primary key in Spring

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, composite-primary-key

Having a DAO like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking")

public class BookingObject implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private CompositeId compositePK;
private LocalDate init_date;
private LocalDate end_date;
private int confirmation;
// getters and setters
```

And composite primary key:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeId implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@NotNull
private String guest;
@NotNull
private String idhousing;
//getters and setters
```

So I can now call `findById(new CompositeId(guest, idhousing));` from my `@RestController`.
The question is: what about if I want to filter by one of the composite primary key's columns, like guest.

I can't do `findByguest` since guest no longer exists in my DAO `BookingObject`. How can I get then the results of "give me all rows where guest is equal to..."

Comment: `select b from BookingObject b where b.compositePK.guest = :guest`. Bu really, really, you should avoid composite function IDs and use autogenerated technical IDs.

Comment: @JBNizet and will autogenerated IDs generate composite primary keys?

Comment: No, my point is precisely that you should avoid using composite functional IDs.

Comment: @JBNizet the problem is, without a composite primary key guest & id_house, I wont be able to book  one specific house more than once. Imagine guest is primary key. Then a user cannot book more than one house, that is not logic, because he can book a house for next week, and another one for the next month. On the other hand, if id_house is primary key, it wont be able to be booked more than one time. A house can be booked the next week and in a year. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: I never advised you to use guest or house as the PK. I advised to use a technical, autogenerated ID. BTW, your PK design is wrong: the same guest can't book the same house at two different dates since [guest, house] is the PK, and must thus be unique.

Comment: I'm gonna read more about those technical IDs. Some questions: does the autogenerated ID reference a specific column (or columns)? I mean that if the algorithm that generates the ID, looks at my table and looks for the primary key (s) declared on it. And what am I supposed to write in `public interface BookingRepository extends CrudRepository<BookingObject, **what goes here?**>` (I wont know the autogenerated primary key's type, won't I?) Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Yes, of course the ID is mapped to a column in the database, just like any other property of an entity. Why wouldn't you know the autogenerated primary key's type? Of course you'll know, since you're the developer deciding to create it. A generated ID is usually a numeric sequence (so you would use Long or Integer as the Java type) or a UUID (and you would then use a String)

Comment: You can also try findByExample where you can create Example object having guest value and get the data

Answer (score 2):

You can try with findByExample

```
    CompositeId compId= new CompositeId();
    compId.setGuest(guestVal);

    BookingObject bookingObj= new BookingObject ();
    bookingObj.setCompositeId(compId);
    Example<BookingObject> bookExample = Example.of(bookingObj);
    List<BookingObject>  objList=repository.findAll(bookExample);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by declaring a query method in the repository class like

```
List<BookingObject> findByCompositePKGuest(String guest);
```

And use this method to get the data from your controller.

The method is written in standard JPA format. The method name is resolved into object and field notion and converted to an actual SQL query in the background.

For more parameters, it'll be like this

```
List<BookingObject> findByCompositePKGuestAndCompositePKIdhousing(String guest, String idhousing);
```

`findByCompositePKGuestAndCompositePKIdhousing` is converted to -> `findBy + compositePK.guest + And + compositePK.idhousing`

---

Another option is to use Spring JPA  filter by Example

Declare `findAll(Example)` method in the repository class

```
List<BookingObject> findAll(Example<BookingObject> bookingObject);
```

And call this method from the controller like this

```
BookingObject bookingObject = new BookingObject();
CompositeId compositeId = new CompositeId();
compositeId.setGuest(guest);
bookingObject.setCompositeId(compositeId);
Example<BookingObject> bookingObjectExample = Example.of(bookingObject);
List<BookingObject> bookingObjectList = bookingRepository.findAll(bookingObjectExample);
```

Refer this [link](https://www.amitph.com/spring-data-jpa-embeddedid-partially/) for more detailed answer

Answer (score -1):

An alternative approach could be to create an `autoincremental key`. It's an integer that automatically increments itself when a new row is inserted in the table. That way the composite primary key is not needed. Only problems is that users can book the same house infinite times, on the same date etc. But it's possible to implement some logic in your servlet in order to check if that user has already booked that house.
Refer to: [w3schools autoincrement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)